# Post values to URL without redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm setting up an SMS service where I have to post some values,
like receiver, sender and message to a specific url at provider.

Pretty simple if I just add a button and in the button event I
make a response.redirect("...url and url parameters with values...")

But I don't want the user to be redirected to another page when the 
button is clicked. I have tried to post the url to a new window with
JavaScript. This is okay, but I'm running into a lot of pop-up blocking issues with
the browser...

Is there any recomendations on how to accomplish that, I think it must 
be a pretty common way to post information to payment services and such.

Best regards.

Comment: Could you not use local storage instead? It would be much simpler?

Comment: Hi - local storage? If much simpler then fine! Do you an example?

Comment: Thinking about it could you put an iframe in with display:none; and change the src of the iframe as require, not exactly pretty but might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With System.Net.WebClient you can call a website without doing a redirect.

```
Dim result As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://...")
```

Comment: Hi - thank you, I didn't know the solution could be written in just 1 line of code..!

Answer (score 1):

When you need to load content in to different pages without reloading you can use local storage which is now widely supported. Similar in a sense to cookies but much more flexible and up to date.

In depth look in to Local Storage [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Brief local storage demo [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)

I can't be sure the exact method of using this with VB or C# but I am sure if you look around you will find it. It is a little hard to tell your exact use case, but ultimately GET variables are loaded in to the page or script on load, s even if you manage to change or update the variable, that won't be accessed until next reload.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the introduction. I have been taken a short look at it, but I can't see how I can resolve the URL with parameters by this one. I need to post values to a URL similar to this one. And of course the user might not se it because of the username and password for the gateway it contains.. 

    https://www.cpsms.dk/sms/?username=user&password=pass&recipient=4512345678&message=test%20message&from=CPSMS

Comment: I think you need to explain your use case slightly better. Why does it go to the URL what is the purpose of sending it to the URL? Why do you need to change it without reloading the page?

Comment: Hi - the solution below by the_lotus was exactly what I needed. Lack of documentation from the provider made it difficult to explain what I exactly needed. Thank you for your replies!